# What are some expressions for making automatic commas for large numbers?

Tags: lua

An example would be: 1000000 to 1,000,000.

If you could make this in Lua that'd be preferred

Answer (score 2):

Lua-users-wiki has an [example implementation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers) for your problem.

```lua
function comma_value(amount)
  local formatted = amount
  while true do
    formatted, k = string.gsub(formatted, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1,%2')
    if (k==0) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatted
end

print(comma_value(1000000))
print(comma_value(111))
print(comma_value(3.141592))
```

Output:

```
1,000,000
111
3.141592
```

---

Alternate version

```lua
function comma_value(n) -- credit http://richard.warburton.it
    local left,num,right = string.match(n,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
    return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
end
```

Comment: `^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$` could be written as `^(.-%d)(%d*)(.*)`

Comment: `gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,')` could written as `gsub('%d%d%d','%0,')`

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local function commas(number)
   return tostring(number) -- Make sure the "number" is a string
      :reverse() -- Reverse the string
      :gsub('%d%d%d', '%0,') -- insert one comma after every 3 numbers
      :gsub(',$', '') -- Remove a trailing comma if present
      :reverse() -- Reverse the string again
      :sub(1) -- a little hack to get rid of the second return value 
end

print(commas(1000000))  -- Pass
print(commas(111))      -- Pass
print(commas(3.141592)) -- Fail
```

Comment: Interesting hack with format! ))) But `:sub(1)` is shorter and safer (doesn't depend on `%`-magic).  BTW, the result of `commas(111)` is not nice.

Comment: Also float numbers aren't working. `print(commas(3.141592))`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff 1. You're right, that's much more robust :) 2. That's because I messed the order of the methods up, thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer to include both fixes :)

Comment: For those interested: I got curious and did some benchmarks vs. the lua-users implementation: https://gist.github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/9a2cc37daf1147aebbb4664b96078d4c